# Makefile not working: Command not found and Error 127

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I'm building `MAKEFILE` on my project and I'm not sure what is wrong it. These are the errors I got after running `make all`:

> client server make: 
> client: Command not found 
> make: *** [Makefile:4: all] Error 127

Here's my `Makefile` code:

```c
LINK=g++

all: 
    client server

client: client.cpp
    $(LINK) client.cpp -o client

server: server.cpp
    $(LINK) server.cpp -o server

clean:
    rm -rf client server
``
```

Answer (score 1):

```
all: 
    client server
```

This specifies that in order to build `all`, `make` needs to execute the following command:

```
client server
```

Since there is no such command called "client" in your path, this is the result that you see: a "command not found" error message.

You obviously meant to specify a dependency, instead of a command:

```
all: client server
```

Comment: But after changing to that, i get this error : make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

Comment: @ThanishK: I think that if you look you'll see that `client` and `server` exist and are up to date. What more do you want Make to do? If you want to suppress that message (which is not an error), you can add a command `@:` to your `all` recipe. (It means *do nothing.)*

Comment: Also, that is **not** an error.  It's an informational message saying make considered what you asked of it and discovered that there was nothing that needed to be done.  You can tell it's not an error because it doesn't have the form of an error message with the `***` and also if you look you'll see that make exited with a success code (0).